# Different response in QA and production enviroments

Tags: java, spring, docker, tomcat, nginx

The service in question has to return response in hindi (like `अहमदाबाद करमली स्पेशल`). For QA environment, the response comes in hindi but when we run the same code in production the response is something gibberish (like `à¤²à¤à¤¾à¤¤à¤¾ à¤¸à¤¿à¤¯à¤¾à¤²`). This gibberish and scrambled response when encoded to ISO-8859-1 and then decoded to UTF-8 produces desired output ( like `कोलकाता`). These is the response when queried with postman.

What can be the issue due to which the same code image produces two distinctly different results. We have tried to include header `charset=utf-8` in the response. Then also it does not render properly in the application in production.

The tech stack is something composed of docker , nginx , tomcat and the language used is java running on spring boot. We tried to check the locale of the machine its running on and it is en.UTF-8.

Can you please make me understand what kind of configuration is wrong ? And is there any way to fix this issue. We want the response in postman to be proper hindi not some gibberish.`Thanks`

Comment: Assuming the difference between QA and prod lies only in ngix and Tomcat setup, I'd look into Tomcat (and verify that you don't have eg. prod-specific Spring-settings) Tomcat delivers data in ISO-8859-1 by default, so compare your server.xml on QA and prod.

Comment: I think the issue is that, the client ( in this case postman ) is not decoding using the correct charset ( which is ```UTF-8``` ) using ```ISO-8859-1``` by default. And this is because perhaps the service does not include ```Content-Type``` header which contains ```charset``` param. When I run the ```curl -I``` command , I don't see the header. This is contradictory to the response in postman which shows the ```Content-Type``` header with ```charset``` as ```utf-8```. I am not able to figure out why the ```Content-Type``` header is missing from the ```curl -I``` command, & whyit works in QA.